# How to interchange integration to get: $\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{x}dz\right)f(x)dx = \int_0^{\infty}\left[\int_z^{\infty}f(x)dx\right]dz$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am wondering how one can interchange the order of integration to get:

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{x}dz\right)f(x)dx = \int_0^{\infty}\left[\int_z^{\infty}f(x)dx\right]dz
$$

It seems like Fubini's theorem is as play here, but I am failing to see how it works intuitively. Does anyone know of a simple way to get this? Thanks.

Comment: It is indeed Fubini, did you draw a picture of the domain? Then it should be clear, I think.

Comment: Both sides are $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\mathbf 1_{0<z<x}\,f(x)\,dx\,dz$$